# Convert string with parantheses into nested list

Tags: python, string, parsing, list

I want to convert a string like this:

```
"asd foo bar ( lol bla ( gee bee ) lee ) ree"
```

to a list like this:

```
["asd","foo","bar",["lol","bla",["gee","bee"],"lee"],"ree"]
```

Is there an easy solution?

edit: It should work for any number and depth of parantheses, but it only has to work for valid strings (no single parantheses)

edit2: Spaces can be seen as delimiters, if it doesn't match it may raise an error or just not work, I don't care. It just has to work for well-formed strings.

Comment: you need to define it more, e.g. can string have space or not, or we can treat any space as delimtter, should it raise error if mismatched parantheses?

Comment: done. (Spaces can be seen as delimiters, if it doesn't match it may raise an error or just not work, I don't care. It just has to work for well-formed strings.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Python's parser to do the job. Just help it a little:

```
>>> a = "asd foo bar ( lol bla ( gee bee ) lee ) ree"
>>> eval(str(a.split()).replace("'(',", '[').replace("')'",']'))
['asd', 'foo', 'bar', ['lol', 'bla', ['gee', 'bee'], 'lee'], 'ree']
```

If you need it to be safe, use `ast.literal_eval` instead!

Comment: Thanks, almost works. Just a little mistake in the second replace method (paranthesis and bracket are swapped)

Answer (score 1):

Pyparsing comes with a built-in helper method, `nestedExpr`:

```
>>> from pyparsing import nestedExpr
>>> a = "asd foo bar ( lol bla ( gee bee ) lee ) ree"
>>> # have to put total string into ()'s
>>> printed nestedExpr().parseString("(%s)" % a).asList()[0]
['asd', 'foo', 'bar', ['lol', 'bla', ['gee', 'bee'], 'lee'], 'ree']
```

The only trick here is that, to keep the parser simple, the whole string has to be wrapped inside a pair of ()'s. The default delimiters for `nestedExpr` are ()'s, but can be any other pair of strings or pyparsing expressions.